# How can I access request object within a custom Serializer Field in the Django REST framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

Consider:

```
class CustomSerializerField(serializers.Field):

    def to_representation(self, obj):
       return obj

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
       # How can I access the request object here?
       return {}
```

And now the ModelSerializer

```
class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   some_field = CustomerSerializerField()

   class Meta:
       model = SomeModel
       fields = ('__all__', )
```

I have tried

```
self.request.user
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DRF is passing the ***outer contexts*** to nested levels during the execution. In your case, the **`SomeModelSerializer`** class passes all the context it took (from the view, probably) to ***its fields and "nested serializers"***

To access the ***`request`*** variable in **`CustomerSerializerField`**, just use,

```
user = self.context['request'].user
```

.